# Python Search within Lists within Lists

Tags: python, list

Why does the following code not work?

```
data = [["4","5"],["3","7"]]
search = "4"
for sublist in data:
    if sublist[1] == "4":
        print ("there"), sublist
        break
    else:
        print("not there")
        break
```

Very sorry for all the confusion, everyone. I was trying to check the entire list and all its sublists and I didn't understand that this would only check the second element of the list, for I forgot Python has a 0th position for the first element. But, how would I check the entire list? remove the "break"s and [1]?

Comment: *What* isn't working?

Comment: The code correctly states "not there" -- there are no sublists in the list whose second element is "4".

Comment: .. your `print`s are strange too.  If you're using Python 2, you don't need the parentheses.  And if you're using Python 3, `print("there"), sublist` won't actually print `sublist`.  You're actually creating a length-2 tuple `(print("there"), sublist)` -- where `print("there")` returns `None`, and then throwing it away.  Probably you meant `print("there", sublist)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do using [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and the [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in function:

```
data = [["4","5"],["3","7"]]
search = "4"

if any(element == search for sublist in data for element in sublist):
    print ("there")
else:
    print("not there")
```

Or even shorter, as pointed by @Veedrac in the comments:

```
if any(search in sublist for sublist in data):
    print ("there")
else:
    print("not there")
```

EDIT: If you want to print the sublist where the element was found, it's necessary to use explicit looping, as shown in @thefourtheye's answer:

```
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        print("there", sublist)
        break
else:
    print("not there")
```

Comment: `any(search in sublist for sublist in data)`

Comment: technically, it's a generator expression not a list comprehension :)

Comment: +1 if you include Veedracs suggestion.

Comment: @Noctua I just did that :)

Comment: @Veedrac thanks for the suggestion, I edited my answer to include it

Comment: @ErikAllik you're right, of course. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, all who contributed and especially Oscar and Veedra, for your thorough and comprehensive answer, but how could this (and please do excuse my limited experience with Python) be expanded so that it might also print the sublist in which the search was found, when I tried print (sublist), I got NameError: name 'sublist' is not defined.

Comment: @user2809263 I edit my answer, see the last part

Answer (score 2):

Lists are 0-indexed in Python, so `["4", "5"][1]` is `"5"`, not `"4"`.

Also, did you want to check whether `"4"` was in the sub-list, or in the sub-list, in the first position? If it's the former, you might want to use `if search in sublist` instead.

Note that as mentioned by Noctua in the comments, you'll only be checking the first sub-list here, since you `break` in any case, so you might want to remove that statement, at the very least in the `else` branch.

Comment: Also, the break should be removed from the else, if he wants to check the complete list.

Comment: @Noctua Yes, it's unclear exactly what the OP is trying to do here, hopefully he'll clarify : )

Comment: The code would be completely pointless if he didn't want to check every sublist, so... :P

Comment: @Noctua Indeed, I hadn't realized that the `break` was in the `else` branch too ; )

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [["4","5"],["3","7"]]
search = "4"
for sublist in data:
    if search in sublist:
        print ("there", sublist)
        break
else:
    print("not there")
```

Comment: wow, identical to my snippet—did you copy-paste?

Comment: I learnt the else part from your code. But I search with `in` operator. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @ErikAllik: it's not identical, check the `print`.

Comment: Come on @ErikAllik, don't squabble. There aren't many derivatives of such simple algorithms so there's no reason to accuse people of foul play.

Answer (score 0):

What Thomas said, + you're breaking in any case, so after the first element in the main list, you're just breaking out of the for-loop and not checking any further elements. What you need is:

```
data = [["4","5"],["3","7"]]
search = "4"
for sublist in data:
    if sublist[0] == "4":
        print "there", sublist
        break
else:
    print "not there"  # executed when the for-loop finishes without break
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
if sublist[1] == "4":
```

you are checking if the 2<sup>nd</sup> element is "4".

To check is `"4"` is *in* `sublist`, use

```
if "4" in sublist:
```

To check if `"4"` is in position 1, use

```
if sublist[0] == "4":
```

---

Additionally, you `break` after every `else`, so if there isn't a match for the first `list` you don't check the later ones! Remove that `break`!